# kivy module would not be installed on python 3.8 in pycharm or cmd

Tags: python-3.8

i tried every rthing downloaded dependecies erased others python3.7 3.5 and checked that pycharm is in enterpred  on 3.8 and i have latest pip version and tried everything but still wouldnt be installed kivy
itt gives alot of liiines of dependencies and the this error

```
   ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
   ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
   ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
   ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
   ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for   full 
   command output.
```

Comment: which OS do you have?

Comment: windows 10  and i used cmd but nothing and by pycharm parametrer stll wont be installedx

Comment: Try to write "import kivy" on "Python.exe" (also called "Python Command Line") to verify if this is a module error from the python distribution you are using (I supose you are using Cpython from the page python.org) or an IDE error (in this case the IDE are you using is Pycharm)